# Build android source code (AOSP) issue

Tags: android, build, android-source

I try to follow tutorial for build android from his source code.

I downloaded the 5.0 version of android AOSP, and all nedded libraries.

Open the console, open the folder of AOSP and go to build:

1.
. build/envsetup.sh

2.
lunch (after press enter)

3.
make -j16 (or 8, or 4...)

In this point I receive a error:

```
XXXXXX@XXXXXXXdevelop:~/androidAOSP$ make -j16
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=6.0.1
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_arm
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-4.4.0-31-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=MASTER
OUT_DIR=out
============================================
Cannot find go tools under ./prebuilts/go/linux-x86/
build/core/soong.mk:25: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'out/soong/.soong.bootstrap'
make: *** [out/soong/.soong.bootstrap] Error 1
make: *** Se borra el archivo 'out/soong/.soong.bootstrap'

#### make failed to build some targets (1 seconds) ####
```

where I was wrong?

**EDIT**

I can solve this issue clonning the go git project in prebuild folder. But I don't know why it is not preinstalled..

Now I have a new error and I can't find info for this file in internet:

-env-aosp_arm.sh

The error is that not find the file:

```
Running kati to generate build-aosp_arm.ninja...
Starting build with ninja
/bin/bash: out/env-aosp_arm.sh: No existe el archivo o el directorio
build/core/ninja.mk:142: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'ninja_wrapper'
make: *** [ninja_wrapper] Error 1

#### make failed to build some targets (1 seconds) ####
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this:

```
. build/envsetup.sh; lunch aosp_arm-eng; make -j4
```

This will tell your machine to -

1. `. build/envsetup.sh` - Execute environment setup for AOSP building tools
2.  `lunch` **`aosp_arm-eng`** - **This is why your make failed**, by adding `aosp_arm-eng` you tell the `make` what kind of OS to build (e.g engineer/ user /user debug).
3. `make -j4` - Start building + compiling

Comment: I solve part of the problem clonning the go project (see EDIT).